# Payara server starts for a brief time but doesn't connect

Tags: intellij-idea, server, payara

I recently had to reinstall IntelliJ IDEA, and ever since then, I've been unable to run this one app that runs on Payara. I have Payara 5.2022.3 (full) installed and the project is using java 11.

This is the server log:

***Artifact my_project-ear:ear exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment…***

***Detected server admin port: 4848***

***Detected server http port: 8080***

And then nothing happens.
And if I terminate the process I get a message:

***Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:4848***

Based on my observation it seems like a process starts running on port 4848 for a few seconds but then stops abruptly.

I checked the CrashDumps and here is the .dpm file in question.
*https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AyLU2HOyXKxREjaDNyIU9eRYMnzaBspw/view?usp=sharing*

I'd already tried:

- Running it on a different port./ Checking if there was not a process blocking used ports.
- "Renewing" the domain.xml in case it was corrupted somehow.
- Using different JDK.
- Reinstalling Windows

I'm positive there is no problem with the app's code (seen a friend run it on his computer today) and I also think no changes happened to the run/debug configuration or the payara and domain configuration ever since it was working before the IDEA reinstall.

(I'm also very new to payara, and software development in general, so I'm not quite as skilled in solving this kind of problem.)

Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: Is there anything related in the server logs? What OS do you use? If the process gets terminated/crashes, what do the system logs say about the crash reason? It might be some security software killing the process.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I use Windows. And also, the server log doesn't show anything about the process crashing. I only found that out based on the activity on the port.

Comment: Check the [event viewer logs](https://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/), crash logs in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\CrashDumps` and the server logs.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I checked the CrashDumps, and this seems to be the error thrown by java.exe. **_The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application._**

Comment: If you need further assistance, please share the `.dmp` crash dump file using some file sharing service and provide the link here.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I tried resolving the issue on my own but wasn't successful so I added the link to the .dmp above. Thank you.

Comment: Try using a different (more recent) Java build / vendor and see if it help. It may be also caused by some third-party security tool.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Getting a different Java vendor worked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the Java version/vendor you are using which is causing the crash of the process. Updating to a more recent Java build or to a different JVM vendor should help.